# Android:How can i make my page slide as the user clicks on button

Tags: android, button, swipeview

How can i make my page slide as the user clicks on button instead of fling action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use animation with the intent,you could either use left to right or right to left animation or vice-versa to acheive this according to your needs.